# Drush site aliases empty within project folder but showing out of the project

Tags: 8, drush

I've got a project that was built using drupal composer project and have a number of drush alias files that site in ~/.drush/sites.

Using a globally installed drush, it appears to pick up the site aliases correctly although didn't appear to recognise the drush config file in ~/.drush/drush.yml.

Conversely, when in the project folder where a vendor/drush folder exists, running drush st shows the drush config files are recognised, as it shows:

```
Drush configs: /Users/me/.drush/drush.yml
               /Users/me/sites/www/client/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
```

However nothing in Drush site alias files and running `drush sa` shows `{}`.

I have checked ~/.drush/drush.yml and in drush: paths: alias-path: it lists

```
- '${env.home}/.drush/sites'
- /etc/drush/sites
```

So am a little perplexed by this!

Comment: Global drush on version 8 and site-specific drush on version 9?

Comment: That looks to be the issue.I've not kept up with drush versions but it seems that drush 9 uses a different site aliases format (yaml). I've reverted back to drush 8.1.16 on my project and looks like I have my site aliases back. Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome! You might also try `drush site:alias-convert` to convert the 8.x aliases to 9.x. I've had varying levels of happiness with this though, I'm not sure a sensible workflow exists just yet for managing sites with both versions on the same box